# Ошибка выполнения в memmove()

Tags: c++

Консольная программа в течение дня запускается периодически с интервалом 5 минут. При выполнении команды `memmove()` нерегулярно и без видимой зависимости возникает исключение в `kernel32.dll`. Исключение даже не перехватывается блоком `try…catch`. Что с этим можно поделать? Какая есть альтернатива использованию `memcpy` и `memmove`? Возможно я неверно выделяю память? Проблемы с памятью на ПК (`Win XP SP3`)? Проект собран на `Win7x64 RAD2009`.

```
void ScanQuery(TADOQuery *adoqMyQuery)
{
String stMemo = "";
int iLink;
void * Buf;
int BufSize;

adoqMyQuery->First();
while (!adoqMyQuery->Eof)
{
    if (VarIsNull(adoqMyQuery->FieldValues["Link"]) || VarIsNull(adoqMyQuery->FieldValues["Signature"]))
    {
        write_to_log_file("Поле Link или Signature не определены (NULL).");
    }
    else
    {
        iLink = adoqMyQuery->FieldByName("Link")->AsInteger;
        stMemo = adoqMyQuery->FieldByName("Signature")->AsString;

        write_to_log_file("Линк обрабатываемой записи  - " + IntToStr(iLink));

        //Проверяем на повторную обработку
        if (!CheckForDublicate(iLink))
        {
            //Обрабатываем запись
            try
            {

                BufSize = (stMemo.Length())*sizeof(char);

                Buf = AllocMem(BufSize);

                //memcpy(Buf,stMemo.t_str(),BufSize);

                memmove(Buf,stMemo.t_str(),BufSize);

                try
                {
                    ViewCertificateInStoreAPI(&iLink, Buf, BufSize);
                }
                catch (Exception *e)
                {
                    ExitCode = -1;
                    write_to_log_file("ViewCertificateInStoreAPI: Сообщение об ошибке : "+e->Message);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception *e)
            {
                ExitCode = -1;
                write_to_log_file("Buf = AllocMem(BufSize) : Сообщение об ошибке: "+e->Message);
            }

            stMemo = "";
            FreeMemory(Buf);
        }
        else
        {
            write_to_log_file("Запись обрабатывалась ранее.");
        }

    }
    adoqMyQuery->Next();
}
```

}

Comment: думаю, что Вам memmove не нужен. Абсолютно. Используйте напрямую

    ViewCertificateInStoreAPI(&iLink, stMemo.t_str(), BufSize);

Comment: Подозрительно выглядит t_str при том, что *sizeof(char). У Вас не в Unicode проект собран?
А вообще, сделайте логирование результатов AllocMem и содержимого stMemo (адрес и содержимое буфера)

Comment: Использовать напрямую пытался с самого начала. В дальнейшем используются функции CryptAPI и CAPICOM и они не отрабатывают по прямой ссылке ViewCertificateInStoreAPI(&iLink, stMemo.t_str(), BufSize). Поэтому пробую делать через memcopy.

Comment: t_str приводим UNICODE к char. Вы хотите сказать, что выделяется недостаточно памяти? Копируемые данные находятся в BASE64 кодировке.

Comment: Каким образом можно сделать логирование результатов AllocMem и содержимого? Можно ссылку на описание метода.

Comment: @Алексей Кондаков, printf(st, "Alloc result: %08X, ", Buf); for ... printf("%02X", ((unsigned char *)Buf)[i]); :) В крайнем случае смотрите OutputDebugString

Comment: @Алексей Кондаков, если у Вас многотредная программа и AllocMem()вызывается в разных потоках, то возможно ошибка заключается в использовании AllocMem() без организации critical section вокруг ее вызова.